# Display full name doctors in all organization sql

Tags: sql, many-to-many

How change doc-id on full name?

```
select w.id,w.doc,w.org
from workplaces w join
     orgs o
     on o.id=w.org     
--where o.active=1 and o.cst='NY' and w.active=1 and w.cst='NY'(table have -     
history, and active=1-it is actual record)     
order by w.org
```

[image: er-model]

[image: example display]

Comment: We need sample table data for all tables involved - as formatted text, not images. Also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. You need to add another `JOIN` for `doctors` table :

```
SELECT
    o.name OrgName
    w.id        
   ,d.name_f +' '+d.name_s DoctorFullName
   ,d.name_p
   ,w.org
FROM workplaces w
JOIN orgs o ON o.id = w.org     
JOIN doctors d ON d.id = w.doc
order by w.org
```